# TensorFlow 2.1 returns Warnings when loaded from terminal and Error when loaded from Jupyter

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.x

I have installed **tensorflow 2.1.0** in a virtualenv on my home laptop (Ubuntu 18.04). When I `import tensorflow as tf` from terminal I get the following warning:

> 2020-03-12 12:17:56.485098: W
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could
>   not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> 2020-03-12 12:17:56.485179: W
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could
>   not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror:
>   libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory
>
> 2020-03-12 12:17:56.485189: W
>   tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen
>   some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with
>   TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are
>   installed properly.

However, the import works and I can run code as usual.

But when I try to do the same in a Jupyter Notebook, I get error. `import tensorflow as tf` returns:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

I have no GPU on my laptop, but tensorflow 2.1 should be able to run on either GPU and CPU-only machines. And in fact I installed it successfully at work with no problems. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: "I have no GPU on my laptop" -> forget the warnings then, you can ignore them (they are for GPU-related libraries). As per jupyter, are you starting the jupyter server in the same python environment as the one from the terminal? (It doesn't seem so)

Comment: yes, it's started in the same environment. That's the real problem

Comment: Check `sys.executable` and `sys.path` inside the notebook to triple-check that it uses the right python install

Comment: `sys.executable` is supposed to appear also in `sys.path`?

Comment: `sys.executable` is the python interpreter you're running. Check that it's the same from the command-line python

Comment: They are different. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the Warnings message by using below code

```
import logging, os
logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
import tensorflow as tf
```

Regarding error on Jupyter notebook,

> Open anaconda-navigator and create new environment and launch the
> jupyter-notebook. Now install tensorflow

```
!pip install tensorflow
```